# How to disable systat on Solaris 10 & 11

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, solaris-11

According to the Solaris server remediations listed in [Solaris for ISPs Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4874/ispplanning-27/index.html), I want to disable `systat` on Solaris 10 and 11. Is there any command to disable `systat` in Solaris 10 and 11 via Command Line?

Comment: The doc you linked to states to [disable a service](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36820/svcstop.html) by that name.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I tried those commands but, `svcs -D systat` and `svcadm disable systat` threw an error saying `svcs: Pattern 'systat' doesn't match any instances or services`.

Comment: Well, in that case, you're done!

Answer (score 1):

That document does not apply to Solaris 10 or 11 - if you read [the introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4874/6j4k302kb/index.html) it discusses installing the "Solaris for ISPs" software on top of Solaris 2.6 using Java 1.1 and the HotJava browser, and the copyright page shows a copyright of 1998.   It's entirely obsolete and you shouldn't trust it for software from this century.

Comment: Ah, wow, even I missed that one!